# Как проверить соприкосновение спрайта игрока и определенного тайла из tilemap

Tags: html5, phaser-framework

Здравствуйте. Делаю 2 *tilemap*, на одном земля, на другом лестница. Делаю гравитацю и с землей все работает отлично, но вот не знаю как проверить соприкосание с тайлом лестницей.
Создаю так:

```js
//Ground
map.ground = game.add.tilemap('map-ground', 32, 32);
map.ground.addTilesetImage('tileset');
layer.ground = map.ground.createLayer(0);
layer.ground.setScale(3);
map.ground.setCollision(174);//ID земли
//Ladders&Hide
map.laddersAndHide = game.add.tilemap('map-ladders&hide', 32, 32);
map.laddersAndHide.addTilesetImage('tileset');
layer.laddersAndHide = map.laddersAndHide.createLayer(0);
layer.laddersAndHide.setScale(3);
map.laddersAndHide.setCollision(168);// ID лестницы
```

Дальше делал такие проверки:

```js
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer.ground);
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer.laddersAndHide, function () {
    console.log(true);
});
```

тогда как я понял столкновение с землей перекрывало столкновение с лестницей т.к. когда я удалял столкновение с землей лестница работала (правда не так как мне надо, я не мог проходить через неё). 
так-же я пробовал:

```js
game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, layer.laddersAndHide, testFunc, null, this);
```

тогда функция testFunc выполнялась постоянно. Возможно из за того, что я не указал конкретный id в layer. Но как возможно укзать?
сейчас остановлся на этом

```js
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, [layer.ground, layer.laddersAndHide], function () {
     console.log(this);
});
```

Думаю может тут можно как то поставить проверку на каком именно layer было соприкосновение?